# Python Date Time Giving Wrong Value

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am running this code to get timestamp from string But it giving wrong value for some particular value.

```
import datetime
import time
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime("20170312025709", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))))
```

It is supposed to return "2017-03-12 02:57:09"## but it giving "2017-03-12 03:57:09"

what could be the reason. I am using python3.

Comment: What's your locale?  I'm in Eastern Standard Time and it prints `2017-03-12 01:57:09` for me.

Comment: Off by one hour during summertime? That's where I'd start looking for the problem.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp and https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.mktime The answer is almost certainly in one of those. That said, why on Earth are you not just using [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) directly instead of running it through all those extra methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a trick question. [daylight savings 2017](https://www.google.com/search?q=daylight%20saving%202017).

```
import datetime
import time

for hour in range(25):
    time_str = "20170312" + str(hour).zfill(2) + "5709"
    print(
        datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
            time.mktime(time.strptime(time_str, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))))
```

Run this and you'll see an error at the end (there were only 23 hours on that day in your default system timezone).

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine on my computer (GMT+8)

Results:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import time
>>> print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime("20170312025709", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))))

2017-03-12 02:57:09
```

You might want to check your local time. Or something to do with daylight Saving time.